# Merge multiple associative arrays to a single array of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 4 associative arrays as per below:

```
$ids  = array(
      '0' => '7' ,
      '1' => '8' ,
      '2' => '9'
);
$names = array (
      '0' => 'Name 1' ,
      '1' => 'Name 2' ,
      '2' => 'another name'
);
$marks = array(
      '0' => '8' ,
      '1' => '5' ,
      '2' => '8'
);
§grade = array(
      '0' => '4' ,
      '1' => '2.5' ,
      '2' => '4'
);
```

I want to "merge" them to a single array, containing associative arrays as per below:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'id' => '7' ,
      'name' => 'Name 1' ,
      'marks' => '8',
      'grade' => '4'
   ),
   array(
      'id' => '8' ,
      'name' => 'Name 2' ,
      'marks' => '5',
      'grade' => '2.5'
   ),
   array(
      'id' => '9' ,
      'name' => 'another name',
      'marks' => '8',
      'grade' => '4'
   )
);
```

I am a new PHP developer and have no idea how to accomplish this. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is your array

```
$ids = array('0' => '7','1' => '8','2' => '9');
$names = array('0' => 'Name 1','1' => 'Name 2','2' => 'another name');
$marks = array('0' => '8','1' => '5','2' => '8');
$grade = array('0' => '4','1' => '2.5','2' => '4');

#New Keys
$keys = array("id","name","marks","grade");
```

**A**. You can use `MultipleIterator`

```
$final = array();
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($ids));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($names));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($marks));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($grade));

foreach ( $mi as $value ) {
    $final[] = array_combine($keys, $value);
}
var_dump($final);
```

**B**. You can use `array_map`

```
$final = array();
foreach ( array_map(null, $ids, $names, $marks, $grade) as $key => $value ) {
    $final[] = array_combine($keys, $value);
}
var_dump($final);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '7' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Name 1' (length=6)
      'marks' => string '8' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => string '8' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Name 2' (length=6)
      'marks' => string '5' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '2.5' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array
      'id' => string '9' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'another name' (length=12)
      'marks' => string '8' (length=1)
      'grade' => string '4' (length=1)
```

Comment: now inner array is array
      0 => string '7' (length=1)
      1 => string 'Name 1' (length=6)
      2 => string '8' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1) I need it as 'id' => '7' ,
      'name' => 'Name 1' ,
      'marks' => '8',
      'grade' => '4' Please help

Comment: +1 I learned 2x things, even if you haven't (yet...) addressed the $key => $value issue ;-)  Nice answer dude.

Comment: How to set  $key => $value Please hlep

Comment: Thank you Baba and Sepster :)

Comment: I got this error array_combine() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: @Saleem  your array must have changed works perfectly http://codepad.viper-7.com/Owve46

Comment: Thank you for you time Baba i am getting print_r as following Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 7 [2] => 8 ) 
Array ( [0] => Student 6 [1] => Test Student [2] => Student 7 ) 
Array ( [0] => 9 [1] => 8 [2] => ) 
Array ( [0] => 4.5 [1] => 4.25 [2] => ) 

Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )

Comment: I am sorry for trouble I was missing $keys = array("id","name","marks","grade"); you guys area great Thank you for help Baba

Comment: Sorry again... How can I add 2 [exam] => sameforall and [exam_id] => sameforall to each inner array.